# Java folder missing

Tags: java, macos

I cant find my Java folder using OSX cmd line. I tried using `find /users -name java`, but no luck. I have looked on many sites most say the library but even though I am the root user I am still getting denied permissions.

Comment: have you tried "which java"  (no quotes)?    When I do that on my Mac I see /usr/bin/java.    IT sounds like "denied permissions" is your real problem.  But could you elaborate on that?  What error do you see exactly and what do you have to do to make it appear?

Comment: They are typically tricky to find. A web search helped me out, though. Try that. PS Mine are `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_13.jdk/Contents/Home` and `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home`.

Comment: @Teto, `which java` on my El Capitan just gives `/usr/bin/java`, it’s not really helpful. Also `$JAVA_HOME` is not set.

Comment: Did you look where the java file points to?   when I do "ls -l java" in "/usr/bin" I see that this is a symbolic link that points to "/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java".  I am using El Capitan.  I guess I really don't understand what you mean when you say you can't find your "Java folder".   Are you looking for the folder that holds the JRE executable?  Are you looking for where one of your own Java programs is located in?  What is motivating your search for "the Java folder"?  Do Java programs not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

If you are looking for a specific version you can use the -v option

for Java 7

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7
```

for Java 8

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8
```